# Autoplaying Audio File In Html

Tags: html, css, atom-editor

Brand new to html and css. I'm trying to get an audio file to play automatically on the page without having to use the player.

```html
 <audio controls autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="beached.wav" type="audio/wav">
    <source src="beached_1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

I thought using autoplay would do the trick but it didn't change anything and if I take "controls" out it just gets rid of the player and there's no way for the audio to play. Any advice would really be appreciated thank you!!

Comment: Are your files served from a server, or from filesystem (with `file://` protocol)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autoplay attribute is a boolean attribute.

When present, the audio will automatically start playing as soon as it can do so without stopping.

use  `<audio controls autoplay>` instead of `<audio controls autoplay="autoplay">`

```
 <audio controls autoplay>

  <source src="beached.wav" type="audio/wav">
       <source src="beached_1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
         </audio>
```

try this one..mayb it would work

Comment: Didn't seem to do the trick :/ Would it have anything to with the browser or text editor??

Comment: this attribute of audio make that audio when that html file will open on browser

Answer (score 0):

## An audio file that will automatically start playing

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The audio tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Hope this will help you,thanks

- https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp

---

you may follow the above link for more depth

Comment: So I figured out that chrome doesn't allow autoplay as a default. As soon as I changed the coding to the example below and opened the page in microsoft edge it worked perfect! Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

The `autoplay` attribute is a Boolean (True/False) attribute. In order to set the autoplay attribute to 'True' **you simply need to include the attribute, no value needs to be set**. Like so:

```
<audio autoplay></audio>
```

However, it's generally not recommended to have audio or video auto-play because it creates an accessibility issue.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#attr-autoplay